# aws sqs: queuing in a loop

Tags: javascript, amazon-sqs

In code below, I have a main loop to get each `'assunto'` in `records(jsonAssuntos)`. After that, I want to send the `'assunto'` to your appropriate queue. The problem is about idSequence. The queue receive the wrong value, sometimes the last number generated.

```
module.exports.consumeMainQueue = async (event, context, callback) => {
  var AssuntoQueueAURL = 'http://localhost:9324/queue/Queue';



for (let recordIndex in event.Records){
var record = event.Records[recordIndex];

var jsonAssuntos = JSON.parse(record.body);
var idMessage = record.messageId;
var idSequence = 0; // initialize *********************
for (var assuntoIndex in jsonAssuntos.dat){
  idSequence++; // increment ********************
  var assunto = jsonAssuntos.dat[assuntoIndex];

  if(assunto.typ == "typ1" || assunto.typ == "typ2" || assunto.typ == "typ3"){
    var infoAssunto = {
      ParentID: idMessage,
      Asssunto: assunto
      IdSequence : idSequence; // send to queue **************
    };
    var paramsAssuntoQueue = {
      MessageBody: JSON.stringify(infoAssunto),
      QueueUrl: assuntoTyp
    };

    queue.sendMessage(paramsAssuntoQueue, function(err, data) {
      if (err) {
        console.log("Error", err);
      }
      else{
        console.log("OK");

        //End Log
      };
    });
  }
  else{
  }
}
};
```

Comment: If fifo queue exists you can use it. I guess sequence is not guraanted in order for queues

Comment: every message sent to queue comes of the same request. The goal is to generate a sequencial number to sent togheter with 'assunto'. The problem looks like sendMessage method dont wait for the loop.